# TS/JS break iterative function with for loop inside

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, iteration, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having an issue to break an iterative loop and return false if a condition was met.

What I'm trying to do actually is to check if a reactive form is empty :

```
 public isEmpty(form: AbstractControl): boolean {
    if (form instanceof FormGroup) {
      for (const key of Object.keys(form.controls)) {
        if (key !== 'modalite') {
          const control = form.get(key);
          if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
            this.isEmpty2(control);
          } else {
            if (control.value && control.value !== '') {
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (form.value && form.value !== '') {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

The problem is that my return false is breaking the for loop but keeps iterating after, so I'm always returning true. What I want to do is that if one formcontrol is not empty I want to return false and break the for loop and the iterative funtion. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how your `return false` could fail to break out of the entire function.  Is the problem perhaps that `this.isEmpty2(control);` should be replaced with `if (!this.isEmpty2(control)) return false;` ?  Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger or adding `console.log` statements to trace what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it would be better to use **required** validator instead of iterating over your controls.

```
const control = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
console.log(control.value);      // ''
console.log(control.status);     // 'INVALID'
```

See: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: I'm checking if my form and subforms values are empty not if they are valid. Not all of my controls are required.

Comment: you can add **required** just on controls whose need it.
What's your goal by checking if they are empty or not ?

Comment: I have a button that user click, and if he has some inputs in the form, he gets a modal saying that he is gonna lose everything he typed in the form. But I don't want that modal to show if user didn't type anything in the form.